# How to change .net framework version for sageframe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sageframe

I have windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013. While I build projects it generates error indicating,

```
Warning 2
The primary reference "D:\SageDemo3.5\SageFrame.Common\bin\Debug\SageFrame.Common.dll" 
could not be resolved because it was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" 
framework.
```

This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5".

Comment: Is SageFrame.Common.dll the output of a project in your solution, or is it a pre-built dll that you're referencing?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have added a project library and then in that library you have taken the refrence of `SageFrame.common` in Viusual studio 2013. Then you built it and get that error.

If this is the condition then please be sure that the project library you have added has the application target framework 4.5.1 not 4.5. Because `SageFrame.Common` is built in 4.5.1 .

In your condition to change the target framework:

- Right click on your project library.
- Select properties (a form will open).
- Select the application tab.
- Select the target framework to 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the version is specified in your web.config, like:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

The other place where it can go wrong is IIS Application Pool, for example if your default Application Pool runs on 4.0 or earlier. So what you have to do is run Internet Information Services Manager, create an Application Pool with 4.5 and then set this application pool to the site you're working on.